# Find and edit a Json file using bash

Tags: json, regex, bash, unix, sed

I have multiple files in the following format with different categories like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "flags": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "name": "test",
    "category": "video",
    "notes": ""
}
```

Now I want to append all the files flags whose category is `video` with string `d`. So my final file should look like the file below:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "flags": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    "name": "test",
    "category": "video",
    "notes": ""
}
```

Now using the following command I am able to find files of my interest, but now I want to work with editing part which I an unable to find as there are 100's of file to edit manually, e.g.

```
find . - name * | xargs grep "\"category\": \"video\"" | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/://g'
```

Comment: Seems like it's caused by the capital `V` in `Video`?
So it should be something like this `"\"category\": \"video\""` instead.

Comment: @SWLim Sorry, That was typo, it's `'v'`. The command I wrote works properly for getting me all files with category `'video'`. Now I want a command to edit my json files flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -l '"category": "video"' | xargs  sed -i -e '/flags/ s/]/, "d"]/'
```

This will find all the filnames which contain line with `"category": "video"`, and then add the `"d"` flag.

**Details:**

```
find . -type f
```

=> Will get all the filenames in your directory

```
xargs grep -l '"category": "video"'
```

=> Will get those filenames which contain the line `"category": "video"`

```
xargs  sed -i -e '/flags/ s/]/, "d"]/'
```

=> Will add the `"d"` letter to the `flags:`line.

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in the same format, this command may help (version for a single file):

```
ex +':/category.*video/norm kkf]i, "d"' -scwq file1.json
```

or:

```
ex +':/flags/,/category/s/"c"/"c", "d"/' -scwq file1.json
```

which is basically using [Ex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)) (now part of Vim).

Explanation:

- `+` - executes Vim command (`man ex`)
- `:/pattern_or_range/cmd` - find pattern, if successful execute another Vim commands (`:h :/`)
- `norm kkf]i` - executes keystrokes in normal mode

  - `kk` - move cursor up twice
  - `f]` - find `]`
  - `i, "d"` - insert `, "d"`
- `-s` - silent mode
- `-cwq` - executes `wq` (write & quit)

For multiple files, use `find` and `-execdir` or extend above `ex` command to:

```
ex +'bufdo!:/category.*video/norm kkf]i, "d"' -scxa *.json
```

Where `bufdo!` executes command for every file, and `-cxa` saves every file. Add `-V1` for extra verbose messages.

If `flags` line is not 2 lines above, then you may perform backward search instead. Or using similar approach to @sps by replacing `]` with `d`.

See also: [How to change previous line when the pattern is found?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8696/467) at [Vim.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @NabaChinde It works for your sample files, maybe you've it them in different format?

Answer (score 0):

***"TWEET!!"*** ... *(yellow flag thown to the ground)* ...  **Time Out!**

What you have, here, is "a JSON file."  You *also* have, at your `#!shebang` command, *your choice of(!)* **full-featured programming languages** ... with intimate and thoroughly-knowledgeale support for JSON ... with which you can very-speedily write your command-file.

Even if it is "theoretically possible" to do this using "bash scripts," this is roughly equivalent to "putting a beautiful stone archway over the front-entrance to a supermarket." Therefore, ***"waste*** ye no time" in such an utterly-profitless pursuit. Write a script, using a language that "honest-to-goodness *knows about(!)* JSON," to decode the contents of the file, then manipulate it *(as a data-structure),* then re-encode it again.

Comment: I did tried using programming languages but whenever I edit a JSON file I needs to be serialize, that was also a headache.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"needs to be serialize(d)."* As far as I know, the **only** way to reliably "edit" a JSON file is to parse it, change the data-structure in memory, then rewrite the entire content of the file. Using a true programming language. There are many subtleties in the format when used with actual data, and clubbing it with "sed" or with some editor is extremely likely to break the file, causing it to be unreadable by anyone or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more appropriate approach using PHP in shell:

> `FILE=foo2.json php -r '$file = $_SERVER["FILE"]; $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($file)); if ($arr->category == "video") { $arr->flags[] = "d"; file_put_contents($file,json_encode($arr)); }'`

Which will load the file, decode into array, add "d" into *flags* property only when category is video, then write back to the file in JSON format.

To run this for every json file, you can use find command, e.g.

```
find . -name "*.json" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    FILE=$file
    # run above PHP command in here
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `jq`:

```
find . -type f | xargs cat | jq 'select(.category=="video") | .flags |= . + ["d"]'
```

Explanation:

```
jq 'select(.category=="video") | .flags |= . + ["d"]'
   # select(.category=="video") =>  filters by category field
   # .flags |= . + ["d"] => Updates the flags array
```